HC-05 bluetooth not working
i connect HC-05 to L293d Driver shield ( vcc to + / Gnd to - / rxd to 1 / txd to 0) but the HC-05 keep flashing red and blue light what does that mean?

Frequency of the blinking?

What is your main controller? Arduino UNO?

The red status LED on the HC-05, has three states:

Rapid Flashing - Looking to pair but unpaired

Slow flashing with a period of around 2 seconds - Paired

Slow double flashes - in AT command mode.


